# EOFError: EOF when reading a line. What is this Error and why is it occuring?

Tags: python

I wanted to write a function that prints True if the pin the user inputted was 4 or 6 in length. I wrote the function, but when I run it outputs this error. How do I fix this error and what is wrong with it in the first place?

```
pin = raw_input("Please enter your four or six digit pins")


def validate_pin(pin):
    if len(pen) == 4 or 6:
        purp =  True
    else:
        purp = False
    return(purp)
    print purp

validate_pin(pin)


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from solution import *
  File "/home/codewarrior/solution.py", line 1, in <module>
    pin = input("Please enter your four or six digit pins")
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

Comment: you may need to change your if condition, by `if len(pin) == 4 or len(pin) == 6:` cuz this way 6 is always true, so the condition will always be verified `if 6:` is equivalent to `if True:`.

Comment: runs fine for me except for that pen typo. Could be an IDE problem; what IDE are you using

Comment: also, the print statement after return will never get executed.

Comment: you seem to be using interpreter from an editor that does not support raw_input or input, compile the file using a terminal and it'll be fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several errors in your code, however, I was unable to create your specific error message. Most likely your raw_input failed.

Here is your fixed code:

```
pin = raw_input("Please enter your four or six digit pins")

def validate_pin(pin):
    if len(pin) in [4, 6]:
        # your old code results in two boolean statements
        # 1) len(pin) == 4, this correctly checks for a length of 4
        # 2) or 6, this is always true, result in your if statement
        #    always being true
        purp =  True
    else:
        purp = False
    print purp
    # if your print statement comes after a return statement,
    # it is never executed
    return(purp)

validate_pin(pin)
```

Comment: I understand know thanks to you. I appreciate your help.